# Android Dynamic Content Design

Tags: android

I want to create a pocket reference application. So, much of the content would be texts, linkbuttons and images.

- I wonder where is a good place to put all of the contents. I could place it hard-coded on the source code, So, when a user click a linkbutton, a new view will be opened and in the source code I specify the TextView and setText, etc. But I think it's not a good idea. Can I put the content in an xml file or in a database? Which one is better for this case?
- I see that we are encouraged to put layout in main.xml. But, from what I read, the xml layout is static, what if I want to put some TextView, but I don't know how many TextView would be displayed, because the content would be loaded dynamically/programmatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it this is what you meant:

You can initialize your application ui by an android xml file layout.
to inflate, you use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29) method.

in your activity's onCreate()-Method or even later, you can then get the TextViews or whatever you want by calling [findViewById(R.id.textview)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29). Note that this method will search all over the layout xml file for the specified id and though blocks the ui thread while searching. if your textview is very near at bottom and many other elements come before it, this can take some time.

if you want to build your own layout dynamically, you have to do this programmatically of course.

for general layout declaring, refer this [tutorial on android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could write the textView in a xml layout and inflate it dynamically in the activity as many times you want
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scroll_project, null);
    //then add the view in linear layout as
    layout.add(view);